# Why is my textView not hidden in my CustomCell class

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making a collapsable cell which expands and contracts when the cell is tapped, but I fail to hide my tableView with the gives constraints in `func checkHeight()`. This is my code of the **CustomCell** class:

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {

class var expandedHeight: CGFloat { get { return 170 } }
class var defaultHeight: CGFloat  { get { return 44  } }

func checkHeight() {
    textView.isHidden = (frame.size.height < CustomCell.expandedHeight)
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

 }

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!


override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

  }

}
```

And this is my code of my VC which has the `TableView`

```
var selectedIndexPath: IndexPath?
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
let previousIndexPath = selectedIndexPath
 if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
     selectedIndexPath = nil
    } else {
            selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }

  var indexPaths : Array<IndexPath> = []
 if let previous = previousIndexPath {
            indexPaths += [previous]
  }
   if let current = selectedIndexPath {
            indexPaths += [current]
   }
   if indexPaths.count > 0 {
   tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: UITableViewRowAnimation.automatic)
        }

}
```

Comment: have you tried reloading the table view?

Comment: You need to reload the cell after you tap it so that it can reload with the new height.  You can do that with/without animation.

Comment: @TaylorM actually my `TableView` is not in this class so I can not refresh it in this class.

Comment: @S.Verma sure, but after calling `checkHeight`, are you reloading your table view in your (table) view controller?

Comment: @TaylorM yes in my `commit editingStyle` I've edited my code.

Comment: I see nothing in your view controller code that changes the height of your cells... am I missing something?

Comment: @TaylorM yes I forgot to add `heightForRowAt` in my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `heightForRowAt` in your class where you have the `TableView`

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
if indexPath == selectedIndexPath {
      return CustomCell.expandedHeight
} 
else {
      return CustomCell.defaultHeight
  }
}
```